# Find zeros of function $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

If I have $$x^2(x-3)(x+3)=0$$ then the solutions are: $$x_{1,2}=0, x_3=3, x_4=-3 $$ or $$x_{1}=0, x_2=3, x_3=-3?$$ So are there 4 or 3 solutions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are $3$ distinct solutions but there are $4$ roots. This has to do with the [multiplicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity_%28mathematics%29) of the roots in a [polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity_%28mathematics%29#Multiplicity_of_a_root_of_a_polynomial). It is often times more in vogue to say that there are $3$ solutions to this but, technically, it must be said that there are $3$ *distinct* roots, as the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra says that there are $d$ roots in $\mathbb{C}$ for a polynomial of degree $d$. Here, $d=4$.

Comment: So 0 is an even zero of this function and -3 and 3 are odd zeros? Is that correct?

Comment: @user111410 Yes, if parity matters for you.